# проблемы с хукам react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

всем привет есть проблема с хуком в моем коже у ма не приложу что делать

есть одно состояние options даю ему свойство по умолчанию при создание хука useState далее использую хук useEffect в нем делаю работа с данными и обновляю состояние options

состояние options меняется в рендоре это видно но в функции onClickBar состояние options прежнее оно не изменяеться

помогите прошу

```
import React, {useState,useEffect,} from 'react'
import CanvasJSReact from '../../../../../lib/canvasjs/canvasjs.react'
import moment from 'moment'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

let CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart

const Subscribers=({typeResurs})=>{

let ParseDate=()=>{
    let data =[]
    for (let i = 0;i<18;i++){
        let rand = Math.random() * (1000 + 1)

        data.push(
            { label: moment().add(-i,'month').format('MM.YY'), active:false, y: Math.floor(rand)  }
        )
    }
    data[0].color = typeResurs==='Gas'? '#00ffde':typeResurs==='HotWater'?'#db8c8c':
        typeResurs==='ColdWater'?'#9cdcf9':'#ffdfab'
    data[0].active=true
    return data
}

let [options, setOptions] = useState(
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        backgroundColor: '#161C30',
        height: 144,
        axisX: {
            // interval: 1,
            labelFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
            labelFontSize:12
        },
        axisY: {
            gridColor: '#353535',
            labelFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
            lineThickness: 0,
            tickColor: '#353535',
            labelFontSize:12

        },

        data: []
    }
)

let onClickBar=(e)=>{
    let dataBar ={...options}
    let data =dataBar.data[0].dataPoints
    let indexActive = data.findIndex((el)=> el.active ===true)
    data[indexActive].active=false
    data[indexActive].color=''

    let index = e.dataPointIndex
    data[index].active=true
    data[index].color=typeResurs==='Gas'? '#00ffde':typeResurs==='HotWater'?'#db8c8c':
        typeResurs==='ColdWater'?'#9cdcf9':'#ffdfab'
    dataBar.data[0].dataPoints=data
    setOptions(dataBar)

}

useEffect(()=>{
    let data ={...options}
    data.data=[{
        type: 'column',
        axisXIndex: 0,
        click: onClickBar,

        showInLegend: false,
        color: typeResurs==='Gas'? '#01A692':typeResurs==='HotWater'?'#EB5757':
            typeResurs==='ColdWater'?'#1F78B4':'#FFBC57',
        dataPoints: ParseDate().reverse()
    }]

    setOptions(data)
},[typeResurs])
return(
    <div className='Dashboard'>
        <div className='contebt-box-panel'>
            <p className='titleGrav'>
                Количество абонентов по месяцам
            </p>
            <CanvasJSChart options={options}/>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
Subscribers.propTypes = {
   typeResurs: PropTypes.string
}
export default Subscribers
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить функцию как зависимость в useEffect [onClickBar, typeResurs]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но не помогло начал постояно рендарить  новые данные

Comment: в useCallback оберните функцию.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему правда на сколько правильно не знают

```
import React, {useState,useEffect,} from 'react'
import CanvasJSReact from '../../../../../lib/canvasjs/canvasjs.react'
import moment from 'moment'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

let CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart

let Subscribers =(props)=>{
let [options,setOpttions]= useState({
    animationEnabled: true,
    backgroundColor: '#161C30',
    height: 144,
    axisX: {
        // interval: 1,
        labelFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        labelFontSize:12
    },
    axisY: {
        gridColor: '#353535',
        labelFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        lineThickness: 0,
        tickColor: '#353535',
        labelFontSize:12

    },
    data: []
})

let addData=()=>{
    let {typeResurs}=props
    let dataBar = {...options}
    dataBar.data[0]={
        type: 'column',
        axisXIndex: 0,
        click: onClickBar,

        showInLegend: false,
        color: typeResurs==='Gas'? '#01A692':typeResurs==='HotWater'?'#EB5757':
            typeResurs==='ColdWater'?'#1F78B4':'#FFBC57',
        dataPoints:ParseDate().reverse()
    }
    setOpttions(dataBar)
}
let ParseDate=()=>{
    let {typeResurs}=props

    let data =[]
    for (let i = 0;i<18;i++){
        let rand = Math.random() * (1000 + 1)

        data.push(
            { label: moment().add(-i,'month').format('MM.YY'), active:false, y: Math.floor(rand)  }
        )
    }
    data[0].color = typeResurs==='Gas'? '#00ffde':typeResurs==='HotWater'?'#db8c8c':
        typeResurs==='ColdWater'?'#9cdcf9':'#ffdfab'
    data[0].active=true
    return data
}
let onClickBar=(e)=>{
    let {typeResurs}=props
    let dataBar ={...options}
    let data =dataBar.data[0].dataPoints
    let indexActive = data.findIndex((el)=> el.active ===true)
    data[indexActive].active=false
    data[indexActive].color=''

    let index = e.dataPointIndex
    data[index].active=true
    data[index].color=typeResurs==='Gas'? '#00ffde':typeResurs==='HotWater'?'#db8c8c':
        typeResurs==='ColdWater'?'#9cdcf9':'#ffdfab'
    dataBar.data[0].dataPoints=data
    setOpttions(dataBar)

}
useEffect(()=>{
    addData()
},[props.typeResurs])


return(
    <div className='Dashboard'>
        <div className='contebt-box-panel'>
            <p className='titleGrav'>
                    Количество абонентов по месяцам
            </p>
            <CanvasJSChart options={options}/>
        </div>
    </div>
)


}
Subscribers.propTypes = {
typeResurs: PropTypes.string.  
}
export default Subscribers
```